# Typescript stateless HOC react-redux injected props typing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, typescript-typings

I'm getting into typescript and I cannot seem to figure out how to properly type my stateless components who all have a redux HOC that injects some props and functions to them.

Here is my `wrapper.tsx`

```
export type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> &
  ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps> & {
    fetchMorePosts: () => void;
  };

const withPostFeedWrapper = <WrapperProps extends Props>(
  WrappedComponent: React.FunctionComponent<WrapperProps>
) => {
  const PostFeed: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
    const { postFeed, fetchPostFeed } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchPostFeed({
        offset: postFeed.offset,
        limit: postFeed.limit,
      });
    }, [fetchPostFeed])

    const fetchMorePosts = useCallback(() => {
      ...do stuff
    }, []);

    return (
      <WrappedComponent
        {...props as WrapperProps}
        fetchMorePosts={fetchMorePosts}
      />
    );
  };

  return connect<
    ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>,
    ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>,
    Props,
    State
  >(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(PostFeed);
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => ({
  postFeed: state.postFeed,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>) => {
  return {
    fetchPostFeed: (variables: FetchPostFeedPostsVariables) =>
      dispatch(fetchPostFeed(variables)),
    dispatch,
  };
};

export default withPostFeedWrapper;
```

Here is my child component

```
import withPostFeedWrapper, { Props } from "./wrapper";

const PostFeed: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  postFeed,
  fetchMorePosts,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      ...stuff
    </>
  );
};

export default withPostFeedWrapper(PostFeed)
```

When I import it as such, it errors out

```
import PostFeed from "containers/_post-feed";

const Homepage: React.FunctionComponent<HomepageProps> = ({
  ...props
}) => {

  return (
    <div className="homepage">
      <PostFeed />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the error

```
import PostFeed
Property 'fetchMorePosts' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Pick<Props, "fetchMorePosts">'.ts(2741)
wrapper.tsx(21, 5): 'fetchMorePosts' is declared here.
```

The way the component is supposed to work, I do not need to pass in the `props` when importing it in another file. The HOC should take care of that. This code runs properly, it is only typescript that is erroring out.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your wrapped component does not need `fetchMorePosts` to be passed in you should type it as `React.FunctionComponent<Omit<Props, 'fetchMorePosts'>>` (the component needs the same as props as in `Props` just without `'fetchMorePosts'`)

Also you can omit the explicit type arguments from `connect` inference will work well (and the type parameters you pass in are wrong, the `TOwnProps` type parameter is added to the required props of the resulting component)

```
const withPostFeedWrapper = <WrapperProps extends Props>(
  WrappedComponent: React.FunctionComponent<WrapperProps>
) => {
  const PostFeed: React.FunctionComponent<Omit<Props, 'fetchMorePosts'>> = (props) => {
    const { postFeed, fetchPostFeed } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchPostFeed({
        offset: postFeed.offset,
        limit: postFeed.limit,
      });
    }, [fetchPostFeed])

    const fetchMorePosts = useCallback(() => {

    }, []);

    return (
      <WrappedComponent
        {...props as WrapperProps}
        fetchMorePosts={fetchMorePosts}
      />
    );
  };

  return connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(PostFeed);
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=52&ssc=3&pln=23&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSAwigDaMBG6A1nAL5xlQQg4AciioMQgFChIsXHDQQAdoqrwefAcNHoYAWlEATfAA9J06PDwAVABb5F7ACLBCYFDDQ3uvfoJFIjY10YOwchAG4pcAs5AEFFAE9YjGAlbw0-QxMIiVyYBLAkOABlGHcigF5cCTg4SEIYADEkAIAuOQgKYhh2xXwQFiQobEZQYB64PoGhrglZ-MK4Zo8bAAUIBuaA9YbCADUUKGAUFkYkQjgqnFmyexS0yhWdppaDAAo3BMYIFAN25c8zy2Bme+0Ox1O5wAlNVaqIYPgoIpYbU4AskO0AESYzA1VGfb6-PGzWZIYwyeDouCrfhgC4VPHIBFIqwFJAAHnRnTgIBQYFK5SsEBpEDpAD44AAyRlIZmKVmFTls7m8sDOVzuTxCkXiqUo2qPTwAWWgSFB7TeMIqEoAbhBgAZIrUuJEJApFA04AB3cZrDYvAIAdSgfMKUEucHZwdDQx1FzJMCQigMFzjYreeOjYEKBjoAkgKkUE2QOgAdI07jBUoo89FCzAoyHs7HaYQxRIrRKcHj3Z6ga92iWMOXK9XawWkw2APIgcbsuPYISGmwm0SgoRiiVVD6tzv6+RKT14eoBgzYZf9gLeKpgVuu1EEYjkSgYN6Wy5dvEPi-+4FvbsPg+nRkN07QnsCpbAd0uKAaioyzhM4GvKW8HjDBgFcFCTqolw2AANo-psrwALpQrkD69vAy6rma-r0o+9BMKwHBvnuAGAV+3D4aR96ovCiLIhmsGNjGub5kok6cQ+OClrJt6ihcKAXFmYZxrMsEGrKxqmqCFQ4NROl0epgEAPTtg+WHErx-FIgeyiqEJqKqgKibaq26G1Kq6puCsbkKXiUJvJeBiWS6uSUTyfIuUgfl0hGbwNOU7TRXu-54khbRwIlialhlZ5zJZbqHvAXkuD5WrCq28UGGVmo2O0tj2E4tUrOy1zYO1cDxEk9yKGKbF4jZyLsZpTy-gOcBvDa4InGchD-FpfpEdsdEHEcs3Qh+UlwDVGorG8hGnlNM2QoQUJQh5O0tZ46FhWF4XFXAAD6wWDmIMAjoovXjhJRbzq2W6TexeXoQZa50bimEfiiQ2TZx7LmYBsmlg0+AUPDZkBZE90RcFEY+iEwUqUMbwveNASFRFAASAhIG4ADmGKIO9n3feJ9ZtVwgPvtaMOygJcMPuyNU2vIjBKYQAByKAgEgFSYjYtMM0gmKI0LeOY0LJki4joWREAA)

Comment: that fixed it, thank you! Good point about inferring the types in `connect`